# What's missing / wrong with my SQL Query? (Doesn't return any row)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010, oledb

Why doesn't my query able to return any rows and not go to *Else* in my conditional statement?

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To dtoffenseinfo2.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim dtoffenseinfo3 As New DataTable              
            Dim adapter3 As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT SUM(Price) AS TPRICE FROM tblFuelTransactionLogs " & _
                              "WHERE Created_Date=#" & Format(dtoffenseinfo2.Rows(i).Item("Dates"), "Short Date") & "#", DBConnection)

            If dtoffenseinfo3.Rows.Count <= 0 Then

            Else
                Dim x As Decimal = dtoffenseinfo3.Rows(0).Item("TPRICE")
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
 Next
```

In my query, the value of dtoffenseinfo2.Rows(i).Item("Dates") comes from a lookup table with dates (for the whole month of September), and per loop, the value of the dtoffenseinfo2.Rows.(i)Item("Dates") is 09/01/2014 up to 09/30/2014 respectively.

I already have 09/18/2014 in both tables but it still doesn't return any row. I am also not getting errors. Am I using SELECT SUM() wrong? Sorry for any obvious mistake.

Comment: Is this against an Access database? Please tag the database. Be aware that your date format is probably ambiguous or incorrect so no records are selected. Even so in most databases, for an aggregate, this will still result in one row with `SUM(Price)` = NULL (not absolutely certain about MS-Access though)

Comment: Thank you! I have tagged it just now. I have tried putting "Format" because even without converting it to "Short Date" and using "Format", I still don't get any row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot

```
 adapter3.Fill(dtoffenseinfo3)
```

That's what's missing. :)

Comment: thanks for the kind reply. Us newbies really should keep it low from them pros.

Answer (score 2):

Who says that your query can't return any rows?  You're not actually executing it so how would you even know?  What's the point of the data adapter if you don't call its `Fill` method?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Problem in your query, you just need to Fill the adapter to let it know what to populate.